# Where can I find a good reference for the ELF file format?

Tags: reference, executable, file-format, elf

I'm in the process of [writing a compiler](https://launchpad.net/7basic) that will be generating ELF executable files for the i386 platform.

However, I need a good reference for the file format (information on headers, relocations, etc.).

Is there such a reference?

Comment: I think you can find the latest ELF specifications here: http://refspecs.freestandards.org/elf/

Comment: Just type `man elf` in terminal on your favorite Linux machine. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wikipedia  [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) gives a decent list of ABI documents to choose from. Consider the very System V ABI and the Intel 386 psABI.